# Lastindexof() isn't working

Tags: java, substring

I have 2 lines of data in text file as example:
Hello!   Morning
Hi!   Evening

I want only last word of a line. I used this code but instead of showing **Evening** it shows **Hi! Evening** where searchName is Hi!

```
try{
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);

            try {
                while((s=in.readLine())!=null){
                    countline++;
                    String[] words=s.split(" ");


                    for(String word:words){
                        if(word.contains(searchName)){
                            System.out.println(words);
                            int lastSpace=word.lastIndexOf(" ");
                            String addres=word.substring(lastSpace+1,word.length());

                            System.out.println(addres);

                        }
                    }
                }
                in.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("No address found for your name..We are updating");
            }
        }finally {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read up on the API of `split()`. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

If you want the last word of a line, you've already got it. It'll be in

```
words[words.length - 1].
```

If you still want to use `lastIndexOf()`, you can, but rather than using `split()` followed by a loop on those elements, you'll just want

```
String addres = word.substring(word.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
```

But you can't really do both. Currently, you're removing all the spaces from the `String` by chopping it up with `split()`, then looking for spaces in each part of the chopped up `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like homework question. So won't provide the exact answer.

The following piece of code should explain you on how to use split() properly and get all the values:

```
String in = "Hello! Morning Hi! Evening";

String[] words = in.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

    if(words[i].equals(yourSearchString)){
      System.out.println("Your Search String" + words[i]);
    }
}
// to get the last word
 String lastWord = words[words.length - 1];
```

Comment: I was confused why my word was not splited with space.Later I noticed , I had used tab between those words.int lastSpace=word.lastIndexOf("\t"); this worked